# Undefined offset, but array items exists

Tags: php, arrays, offset

I have problem which i can't understand.
I get error `Undefined offset` with this code:

```
$date = $this->date;
$dateArr = explode('-', $date);
$newDate = $dateArr[2] . '.' . $dateArr[1] . '.' . $dateArr[0];
```

`$this->date` is a string like `"2013-11-10"`

`var_dump($dateArr)` says, that there are these values in the array, same as Debugger.

I dont understand why do i get this error. This is only a "notice", but it makes me angry.
What is funny the date is saved to the database anyways, and this is correct (like `$newDate` is built correctly).

-- edit

By doing this i want to convert the date from yyyy-mm-dd to dd-mm-yyyy, then convert this to unix timestamp.

Comment: Could you add some `var_dump`s to the code? What does `var_dump($date)` give you? What does your `var_dump($dateArr)` show?

Comment: What is the exact error message (with the line number)?

Comment: Add Echo "$date";.Is it showing the date 2013-11-10

Comment: @user2648239 If you do *that*, you'll see `$date` instead of the contents of that variable.

Comment: sorry i know echo either without quotes or with double quotes.

Comment: echo of `$date` displays "2012-11-19". var_dump displays `string "2012-11-19" length 11`

Comment: are you Outputting $dateArr or $newDate?You should Echo "$newDate"; for output.I m getting the output correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$this->date` is actually set, there is no need for your multi manipulations just use [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) to get the timestamp and then [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to format.

```
// To change formatting to 10.11.2013
$newDate = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($this->date));

// To turn date into unix timestamp 1384038000
$newDate = strtotime($this->date);
```

Comment: I don't want to display this date on the screen. I want to convert yyyy-mm-dd to unix timestamp, and save it in db. I have should say it before.

Comment: You might of missed the edit, refresh your page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get "10.11.2013" as a result - you'll get it (your code works OK), but only in case `$this->date` is set and that is really string like `"2013-11-10"` (I'm sure it is not). In all other cases when your `explode` will fail and will return different result (array that does not have 3 elements) - you'll get offset.

Comment: It really is, this is the point. Debugger, var_dumb, print_r, all of these thing says that everything is set properly. var_dumb, and print_r shows 3 items in array.

Comment: By the way, why do you need unix timestamp for storing time? If you want to save it as TIMESTAMP to, e.g. MySQL, you just need to form string like this `$this->date.' 00:00:00'`. Why do you need unix timestamp for that?